# Как реализовать обновляемый белый/чёрный список для определённых почтовых ящиков?

Tags: linux, postfix, dovecot

интересует возможно ли реализовать в postfix'е возможность сделать динамический(обновляемый) белый/чёрный список адресатов
Нужно примерно следующие, имеется 3 ящика post1@example.ru, post2@example.ru, post3@example.ru.
Запретить им принимать почту от адресатов которым они ни разу не отправляли письма, то есть если они отправили письмо на vasyapupkin@mail.ru то он добавляется в белый список и в дальнейшем письма с этого ящика спокойно доходят, если же в этом белом списке нету данного адреса то идёт пересылка письма допустим на ящик blacklist@example.ru

Comment: 1. Это нестандартное поведение SMTP сервера. 2. Postfix конечно крутой и обладает кучей тумблеров для тюнинга, но «запоминание» адреса получателя - это отдельная задача. 3. Я бы смотрел в сторону внешнего анализатора (milter), на подобие spamassassin, openDKIM и т.п. Скорее всего придется писать свой, т.к. сомневаюсь, что есть готовый под такую задачу. Хотя всякое бывает, может кто-то уже написал и на гитхаб положил...

Comment: [аналогичный вопрос](http://postfix.1071664.n5.nabble.com/Recipient-rewrite-based-on-sender-td61161.html) и [другой вопрос, на который ссылаются в первом](http://postfix.1071664.n5.nabble.com/recipient-rewrite-when-sender-lt-gt-td60838.html)